# Slack post payload in wrong format

Tags: python, slack

How to get payload printed in json format

Getting payload like %7B%22type%22%3A%22interactive_message%22%2C%22actions%22%3A%5B%7B%22

```
2020-02-17 14:09:22,624 200 POST /slack/message_actions HTTP/1.1 Host: myipteventsbot.tunnel.com X-Real-IP: 3.93.14.114 Content-Length: 5159 User-Agent: Slackbot 1.0 (+https://api.slack.com/robots) Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate Accept: application/json,*/* 
X-Slack-Signature: v0=96ab9dd1e89047f6cea117313a17989eb25849f7a86ad1f1eff8a0be692238cf X-Slack-Request-Timestamp: 1581970162 Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded 
payload=%7B%22type%22%3A%22interactive_message%22%2C%22actions%22%3A%5B%7B%22name%22%3A%22fullfilment_list%22%2C%22type%22%3A%22select%22%2C%22selected_options%22%3A%5B%7B%22value%22%3A%22spu%22%7D%5D%7D%5D%2C%22callback_id%22%3A%22test%22%2C%22team%22%3A%7B%22id%22%3A%22TFHGD33RV%22%2C%22domain%22%3A%22bby-sandbox-general%22%2C%22enterprise_id%22%3A%22EFGBDRLNP%22%2C%22enterprise_name%22%3A%22Best+Buy+Test%22%7D%2C%22channel%22%3A%7B%22id%22%3A%22DTHBLNXD0%22%2C%22name%22%3A%22directmessage%22%7D%2C%22user%22%3A%7B%22id%22%3A%22WLCLZ2LDP%22%2C%22name%22%3A%22a6002043%22%2C%
```

My code snippet

```
@app.route("/slack/message_actions", methods=["POST"])
def message_actions():

    # Parse the request payload
    form_json = json.loads(request.form["payload"])

    # Verify that the request came from Slack
    verify_slack_token(form_json["token"])

    # Check to see what the user's selection was and update the message accordingly
    selection = form_json["actions"][0]["selected_options"][0]["value"]

    if selection == "spu":
        message_text = "spu"
    else:
        message_text = "sth"

    response = slack_client.api_call(
        "chat.update",
        channel=form_json["channel"]["id"],
        ts=form_json["message_ts"],
        text="One {} order coming up! :coffee:".format(message_text),
        attachments=[] # empty `attachments` to clear the existing massage attachments
    )

    # Send an HTTP 200 response with empty body so Slack knows we're done here
    return make_response("", 200)
```

Answer (score 0):

figured out i need update my code as below

```
request.form.get('payload')
```